# In Flutter, how to make a YouTube-like expandable and dismissable view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How to create an expanded view similar to the YouTube mobile app Drag down to minimise, and if I drag down again, it will dissmiss. If I minimise it and drag it up, it will open full screen with animation.

I tried a number of things with animatedBuilder and gesture detector, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can forsure build that kind of UI with **AnimatatedBuilder**.

But if you want to save some time then you can use **miniplayer** [package](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) in order to implement the UI.

You can use a `Stack` in combination with a `custom Navigator` in order to achieve this UI.

There also a tutorial on YouTube for that: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umhl2hakkcY&t=1649s)